# Why doesn't this return s?

Tags: python

Trying to make a function to use the SUVAT equations to calculate each variable, and the functions aren't returning the values that should have been calculated.

```
def float_input(text: str) -> float:
while True:
    try:
        num = float(input(text))
    except ValueError:
        num = ''
        break
    else:
        return num

print ('Enter the values of the following variables if they have been given')
s = float_input('Displacement')
u = float_input('Initial Velocity')
v = float_input('Final Velocity')
a = float_input('Acceleration')
t = float_input('Time')

def find_s (s, u, v, a, t):
    if s == '':
        if '' not in (v, u, a):
            es = 's = (v^2-u^2)/(2a)'
            s = ((v**2)-(u**2))/(2*a)
        elif '' not in (u, t, a):
            es = 's = ut + 1/2at^2'
            s = (u*t) + (0.5*a*t**2)
        elif '' not in (v, a, t):
            es = 's = vt - 1/2at^2'
            s = (v*t)-(0.5*a*t**2)
        elif '' not in (v, u, t):
            es = 's = t(v+u)/2'
            s = (0.5*(v+u))*t
        return (s, es)
    else:
        es = ''
        return (s, es)

s, es = find_s (s, u, v, a, t)
print (s)
```

I've input values for u, v, and a, which should mean s is calculated, but this prints 'None' instead of the value of s based on the calculations, why, and how would I fix it?

Comment: Your syntax is weird, you should write instead `def float_input(str)`

Comment: Please fix the code formatting, right now it's impossible to tell what belong to what. Also please provide sample input (see [mcve])

Comment: Add comments too

Comment: be careful with the indentation, the return before the last `else` is not well indented

Comment: You are never assigning the value of `s` from your function.

Comment: @toti08 That's type annotations.

Comment: @toti08 - That's a perfectly valid syntax (the function signature definition, that is) for a type-hinted function.

Comment: My bad, I didn't know, I'll check that!

Comment: also, the fact that there's a function before the print statement doesn't mean it will be executed unless you call the function, like this `print(find_s(s, u, v, a, t)[0])`

Comment: edited the code to call the function, but a new error has come up, it says that there is invalid syntax in 'elif '' not in (u, t, a):

Answer (score 3):

Note this behavior:

```
>>> def float_input(text: str) -> float:
        while True:
            try:
                num = float(input(text))
            except ValueError:
                num = ''
                break
            else:
                return num

>>> float_input('Foo: ')
Foo: NotAFloat
>>>
```

As you can see, the `float_input` function returns even though I haven’t entered a float. This is because when you encounter a `ValueError` you *break* from the while loop, so you don’t actually re-execute the loop body.

Since you break the loop, code execution continues after the loop where there is nothing, so nothing (`None`) is returned.

You probably meant to write it like this:

```
>>> def float_input(text: str) -> float:
        while True:
            try:
                return float(input(text))
            except ValueError:
                pass


>>> float_input('Foo: ')
Foo: NotAFloat
Foo: MaybeAFloat?
Foo: 123foo
Foo: 123
123.0
```

---

Once you have fixed that, of course the next problem with your code is that you never actually call `find_s`, so no calculations are done. Instead, you just print the value for the “Displacement” input.

Comment: Is there a way I can make it so that nothing has to be entered, and the next input can be entered?

Comment: You mean to skip values? You could check if the `input()` call returns an empty string and handle that separately, instead of attempting to parse it as a float immediately.